# Unable to init / configure elastic beanstack in windows,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After I give `eb init` command, I enter new access key and secret key from the security credentials of AWS (https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/security_credentials). But keep getting error

```
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Signature expired: 2020********* is now earlier than 2020********** (2020******** - 5 min.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your system clock. It can't be different then 15 min from [AWS clocks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationStringToSign):

> the client timestamp included with an authenticated request must be **within 15 minutes** of the Amazon S3 system time when the request is received.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was with clock